# Customize the kendo grid column filter by string and boolean value in a single column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to customize one Kendo grid column. The column contains the string format value. It works with string filter. Now I want to extend it by adding radio button options in the single column to filter the data. So, this new filter option does not replace the regular column filtering options. They co-exist. I am using Kendo 2015.3.930 version which does not have the feature for "Isnull", "Isempty", "Isnotnull", "isnotempty" operators for the string filter. This is why I want to add radio button section to show filter the items which have value and do not have by customizing the filter text as well. And it should be possible to both string and boolean filter together. Here I am not figuring out the concept technically, how can I achieve it. The existing code is written in razor format. Any suggestions or example?